# Creating a sensible line chart to compare the average with the actual

Tags: r

I have the following dataset

[image]

I want to create a line chart comparing the historical average vs 2016 monthly highway fatalities . I want to use ggplot with the graphing.

I had more than one attempt but still I receive errors like (Error: could not find function "ggplot2")

```
ggplot(Homework_8_data, aes(x = Months)) + 

  geom_(aes(y = Ave_since_2002), colour="blue") + 

  geom_line(aes(y = X2016), colour = "grey") + 

  ylab(label="Average and actual highway fatalities") + 

  xlab(label="Months")
```

I need someone help me understand the error I did and correct it for me.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to install ggplot2 :

`install.packages("ggplot2")`

and then load it :

`library(ggplot2)`